# Add Screen Sharing to my web app?

Tags: javascript, screensharing

I have to make a web application that imitates Skype. I am using php, javascript, html and css to do this. I am allowed to use open-sourced libraries and other libraries.

I need to implement a screen sharing feature. How do I do this? My research led me to believe I need to code a java applet but I have no idea how to do this. This was assigned today and I just have 3 weeks to implement it. How should I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You may find one of those projects useful:

- http://kanaka.github.com/noVNC/
- http://guac-dev.org
- http://www.cybelesoft.com/thinvnc/

Comment: Well, from the question, it seems to me that he wants a sharing server; all of those are just clients; you can use them to access a remote screen from a browser, but the question seems to ask the exact opposite, which is not so trivial.

Answer (score 1):

no, you would need at minimum flash, probably some native/java code to do screen sharing, this is not going to happen with php javascript and html

UPDATE: WebRTC can help you with it but support in browsers is still kind of up in the air.

Comment: hmm, i never worked with java before, i have worked heavily with c++ before and it seems the same with some differences. any tutorials you would recommend on how to build java applets?

Comment: If you do not know how to do that, this is not a 3 weeks assignment...Talk to your teacher about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is far from being an easy job, but if you want to try it, there appears to be an open-source project [here](http://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/) (it uses [Red5 media server](http://www.red5.org/) to transmit the video stream), but it's probably just basic functionality for a single user only.

> I am using php, javascript, html and css

Even with HTML5, that won't be enough without additional client plugins. You will need Flash, Java or Silverlight installed on all clients which want to share their desktops (for viewing and interaction, basic HTML5 would suffice). I have a feeling this might be difficult to learn from scratch in three weeks time.

Comment: luckily, my professor changed his mind about implementing this, but this would have been exactly when i was looking for.